# Power Query - conditional column with multiple entry criteria

Tags: excel, powerquery

I would like to ask for your help with the power query-related problem I cannot solve on my own:

One of the columns [address] contains data like this :

```
    Science Park 404, 1098 XH Amsterdam, Netherlands
    Laan van Malkenschoten 20, 7333 NP Apeldoorn, NL
    plac Europejski 1, 00-844 Warszawa, Poland
    Adrianastraat 6, 3014 XL Rotterdam, Netherlands
    C. Co Brava, 109, 17411 Vidreres, Girona, Spain
```

I also have a list of keywords, that contain: Amsterdam, Apeldoorn, Rotterdam

**What I need is that power query checks if [address] column contains any of the keywords, and if yes, in a new custom column display ‘MATCH’:**

```
    Science Park 404, 1098 XH Amsterdam, Netherlands MATCH
    Laan van Malkenschoten 20, 7333 NP Apeldoorn, NL MATCH
    plac Europejski 1, 00-844 Warszawa, Poland
    Adrianastraat 6, 3014 XL Rotterdam, Netherlands  MATCH
    C. Co Brava, 109, 17411 Vidreres, Girona, Spain
```

The list of keywords is stored in the same Excel file, in a one-column table called ‘CITIES_NL’

In theory, I can create a conditional column and hard-code the keywords, however I cannot do it for two reasons:

- the list needs to be dynamic, it is likely that new keywords will be added on a daily basis
- in production, the list of keywords would consist of 75k items, it is impossible to enter this to PQ

To achieve the same in Excel, without PQ, I would use this formula:

```
    =IF(--SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(CITIES_NL,address)))>0,"MATCH","")
```

however, this has to be done by PQ, as this is only one of the steps for preparing my data

I would appreciate your help!

Michal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, add both your `ADDRESS` and `CITIES_NL` table to power query editor, convert `CITIES_NL` into a **List**, then add a custom column to the `ADDRESS` table using the following formula:

```
=if List.Count(Splitter.SplitTextByAnyDelimiter(CITIES_NL)([Column1]))>1 then "MATCH" else null
```

> The logic is to split `ADDRESS` by any words contained in the `CITIES_NL` list, and count how many sub-strings are there. If the result is greater than `1` which means at least one key word was found, then use **IF** to return `MATCH` otherwise `(null)`.

Replace `[Column1]` with the actual column name in your case.

Here is the full Power Query M code for your reference:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="ADDRESS"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each if List.Count(Splitter.SplitTextByAnyDelimiter(CITIES_NL)([Column1]))>1 then "MATCH" else "")
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

> Please note the match will be case sensitive. If you want a case-insensitive match, you can add an index column to the `ADDRESS` table, make a duplicate of the `ADDRESS` query, convert both `ADDRESS` and `CITIES_NL` to lowercase then do the match, and then merge the matched query with the original `ADDRESS` query by the index number.

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks Terry! This is exactly what I needed! BR, Michal

Answer (score 1):

You can do this dynamically by adding a custom column that for each address checks each keyword to see if it is a substring and counts the number of keywords that are a substring of the address. If the `count > 0`, then return `"MATCH"`.

Here's one way to do this:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Previous Step Reference", "Custom Column Name",
      (C) => if List.Count(
                    List.Select(CITIES_NL[keyword], each Text.Contains(C[address], _))
                ) > 0
             then "MATCH"
             else null,
      type text)
```

The syntax is a bit different but the logic is very similar to your Excel formula.

Note that I defined a context `C` so that I could reference the `address` from that row context within the context of the `CITIES_NL[keyword]` list.